# gitlab-runner:Pipeling is pending infinitely

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I install a Specific Runners,and the status is actived.

my .gitlab-ci.ymi file code:

```
stages:
  - build

build_maven:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo "hello CI/CD"
  tags: 
    - vue-dev-pub
```

when I push the master branch,the gitlab-runner is running,but it's pending infinitely。

the job page show:

> ## This job has not started yet
>
> This job is in pending state and is waiting to be picked by a runner

if I excute the runner manually,the job can pass.

the command of gitlab-runner verify shows:

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=24616 revision=d0b76032 version=12.0.2
WARNING: Running in user-mode.                     
WARNING: The user-mode requires you to manually start builds processing: 
WARNING: $ gitlab-runner run                       
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:                 
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...                   
                                                   
Verifying runner... is alive                        runner=T4iKvsT3
```

I am waiting for you respond,thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If you run the runner manually in debug mode `gitlab-runner --debug run` you may see the actual error message, in my case it was:

`WARNING: Failed to process runner builds=0 error=failed to update executor: missing Machine options executor=docker+machine runner=pSUsX4yR`

That's because on runner creation, I selected option `docker+machine` rather than `docker`.

After amending `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` to `docker` and running `gitlab-runner restart` followed by `gitlab-runner verify`, pipeline started running again.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with my (shell) runners on linux. It would work fine on runners installed and registered on one of my computers but not another. (Even as tags matched correctly in runner and job)

After
`gitlab-runner register` I would get:

> New runner. Has not connected yet

After
`gitlab-runner verify` that error would go away. But I would get

> This job is in pending state and is waiting to be picked by a runner

After
`gitlab-runner restart`

It would all work.

`gitlab-runner status`

> gitlab-runner: Service is running!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have tagged your runner but your job has no tags. Refer :[how to run untagged jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371027/10570524)
[image]
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371027/10570524

Answer (score 0):

The tags section in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file specifies this job has to be picked by a runner that has the same tags ([reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags)).

```
tags: 
    - vue-dev-pub
```

So unless there is actually a runner available for your project that has the `vue-dev-pub` tag it will keep waiting for one to become available.

Comment: my runner is registered with a tag 'vue-dev-pub',I feel gitlab-runner is not very friendly

Comment: It would help if you could share your runners config file

Answer (score 0):

first, remove the old config in sys

```
rm /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.servicetemd
```

now, you need install gitlab-runner with gitlab user:

```
gitlab-runner install --user=gitlab-runner --working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner
```

root installations fail

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is important to check https://status.gitlab.com/
It may show that some services are malfunctioning.
For example in my case there was troubles with both:

```
CI/CD - GitLab SaaS Shared Runners
```

and

```
CI/CD - GitLab SaaS Private Runners
```

So you need to wait till those service will back in action