# This job is stuck because the project doesn't have any runners online assigned to it. Go to Runners page

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

i'm really new with this, when I started the project, I put this code the .gitlab-ci.yml, and work fine, but today I tried to merge and the pipeline never end, always still in pending.

any idea?

one week ago work

file: .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: node:10

before_script:
  - apt update
  - apt-get install -y nodejs
  - npm install -y npm@6.11.0
  - nodejs -v
  - npm -v
  - ls -la -F
  - yarn

# CI/CD Pipeline
stages:
  - lint

lint: 
  stage: 'lint'
  script: 
  - yarn
  - yarn lint

# Setup Node.js cache for the runners
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
```

[image: The error]

[image: Runners in GitLab]

Comment: your runner is offline , can you check if this runner is enabled for this project https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/#enable-a-specific-runner-for-a-specific-project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370840/this-job-is-stuck-because-the-project-doesnt-have-any-runners-online-assigned